# Schema from dry run flags required fields as nullable

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the Java API to get the schema from a query using a dry run, but the schema I get back contains nullable fields when they should actually be required.

For example, with this query:

```
SELECT word FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
```

Even though the "word" field is required in the table, the result I get back is

```
com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableSchema = 
{"fields":[{"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"word","type":"STRING"}]}
```

Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can happen - query results may have different NULLABLE vs. REQUIRED from the table schema, even if query trivially just selects fields. In general propagation of column nullability is fragile, so it is probably better not to rely on it.

P.S. It looks like you used standard SQL https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/ (although similar things may happen with legacy SQL as well).

Comment: I think getting the schema from query dry-run is only available for standard SQL - previously we were getting the schema by creating a view, which correctly preserved required fields. Can you elaborate more on how the query results may have nulls for fields that are required? And would there be another way to get the same schema as the view (since views are not yet supported for standard SQL)?

Comment: Let me ask differently - why do you care whether it will be labeled as REQUIRED or NULLABLE ? What changes in your application ?

Comment: My team is building a type-safe Scala api around the big query client, and part of our approach is to map nullable fields to Scala Option types. This in turn means that users of this type-safe API will see Option types for fields they expect to be required. The applications can of course freely unpack the option, but it would be a source of confusion and somewhat defeats the purpose of type safety. With legacy SQL, we got the schema by creating a view from the query, which preserved required fields. But now using a dry run, required fields come back as nullable so everything is an Option.

Comment: any thoughts? Should we try to find another approach?

Comment: With standard SQL you will never get REQUIRED in the output schema, it will always mark non-repeated fields as NULLABLE. If you will create view (once that is supported), it will be NULLABLE as well. But as you say above - it isn't wrong, just maybe less precise than it could be.